# While debugging in eclipse, eclipse hides some variables

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging my program in eclipse and facing some strange problem. I have a list `fileList1`, which is a list of objects `files`, which has 2 properties:

```
fileName 
versionList
```

Please have a look on this picture, you will understand my problem.

[image]

While debugging, I noticed that when I add object `files` in `fileList1` using a for loop, it works fine and the object files is added. But when I extract the FileList1, it doesn't shows all nodes information, for example, here you can see:

When I extracted FileList1[0], only filename is shown. The next filed, which should show versionList is blank.

Again, When I extracted FileList1[2],nothing is shown, neither filename or versionList.

If I mistakenly doesn't add anything in a particular file, then atleast the variable name , like `fileName` and `versionList` should be shown with null properties. But its not the case here. Also, sometimes, the `fileName` variable in debugger variables view shown one value and if I click on it to extract, it shows another value.

I think the problem is with debugger. Its not updating properly. My output is also coming weird. It seems new entries are replacing old entries, although I did not used any replace function for list, just used `fileList1.add(file)`. I am not understanding, whats the problem here.

I already checked internet and stackoverflow for a solution. But did not found similar topic. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why the values are not shown, but you can still check the value using ctrl+shift+ I command. Just type a line which will fetch your value select it and press ctrl+shift+ I. It will execute the command. like FileList1[0].getFileName()

Comment: Which OS? Do the values show up when you scroll the view? Or when you scroll them out of the visible area? When you resize the window?

Comment: The OS is windows 7. When I scroll them out in visible area, it shows the value. But nothing changes if resize the window.

Comment: Interesting; I have a similar effect on Ubuntu 14.04. Does it help when you click into the empty cells? Which version of Eclipse? Which version of Java do you use to run Eclipse? Which version runs the program?

Comment: Normally, if you click on empty cells, it shows the value on the extracted window, but the cells are still empty. My eclipse version is Luna. I am using JDK 8.